# Datepicker not working with .after in a switch/case

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to have **Datepicker** attached to the "date" fieldType option I've included using .after in a switch/case

```
case "date":
    $this.after('<input type="text" class="value cat_textbox datepicker" />')
    break;
```

Currently, I am getting the `<input>` container, but I am not seeing the calendar button. Plus, it is not actioning the Datepicker when I click on the container.

[image]

**Note:**
**Datepicker** is working perfectly fine when I add `<input type="text" class="value cat_textbox datepicker" />` directly into the `<body>`.

[image]

All the other switch/case options are working perfectly. (see snippet of function below).

```
/*
** This changes the fieldType options when
** a different Field (age, gender, etc) is selected
*/
function onOperatorSelectChange(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var option = $this.find("> :selected");
    var container = $this.parents(".rule");
    var fieldSelect = container.find(".field");
    var currentValue = container.find(".value");
    var val = currentValue.val();

    switch(option.data("fieldType")) {
        case "none": 
            $this.after($("<input>", {"type": "hidden", "class": "value"}));
            break;
        case "text":
            $this.after($("<input>", {"type": "text", "class": "value"}));
            break;
        case "date":
            $this.after('<input type="text" class="value cat_textbox datepicker" />')
            break;
        case "textarea":
            $this.after($("<textarea>", {"class": "value"}));
            break;
        case "select":
            var select = $("<select>", {"class": "value"});
            var options = fieldSelect.find("> :selected").data("options");
            for(var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = options[i];
                select.append($("<option>", {"text": opt.label || opt.name, "value": opt.name}));
            }
            $this.after(select);
    break;
}
currentValue.remove();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke datepicker method after creating datepicker textbox

change your code inside the case "date":

try following codes

```
case "date":
    $this.after('<input type="text" class="value cat_textbox datepicker" />');
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange:'-50:+20'
    });
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks Sarath. I copied your codes and replaced mine...no change. Same problem still. Any further thoughts?

Comment: Tried a few approaches from what you provided. Still no response from clicking on the input box??
`case "date":
        $this.after('<input type="text" value="yyyy/mm/dd" class="value cat_textbox datepicker" />');
  $( 'input.datepicker' ).on({
            click: function(e) {
                e.target.preventDefault();
                $(this).datepicker({
                    changeYear: true, changeMonth: true
                });
            }
         });
    break;
`

Comment: its working fine for me... can you please check the console is any javascript error is occurred ?

Comment: Ok, after hearing that it was working, I decided to test in a different browser. Pow! It worked in perfectly Opera. ALL THIS TIME!! Do you know why it isn't working in Safari on OSX v10.9.1? Or, how would I correct this issue with Safari?

Comment: May be problem with your browser cache .. clear the cache or all the history of your browser and try again

Comment: Wait a minute. Now, the calendar icon appears beside the input box as it is supposed to. The calendar also pops up. I have control of most of the calendar controls, except: 1) when I click on the days/numbers, nothing happens, and 2) when I click anywhere off the calendar, nothing happens...

Comment: As suggested, I tried clearing the cache. No change. Recall, that the calendar functions flawlessly in Safari when I add `<input>` into the HTML `body`. Yet, when I create the `<input>` from js, it isn't functioning in Safari. The exact opposite is happening with Opera. Any ideas?